ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build -- --configuration production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
I am trying to build my angular application thru Docker and facing errors while executing "RUN npm run build" command
This is my Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:lts-alpine AS build

# Install necessary build tools for Angular Material
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    python3 \
    make \
    g++ \
    libc6-compat

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json for dependency installation
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

# Install all dependencies (including Angular Material)
RUN npm install --silent

# Copy the rest of the application source code
COPY . .

# Build the Angular application in production mode
RUN npm run build -- --configuration production

# Stage 2: Serve the application using Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the build output from Stage 1 to Nginx's HTML directory
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/your-angular-app-name /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 8088 (or the port you want to serve)
EXPOSE 8088

# Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

these are some of the error im facing after build error.
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-connection-parameter' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'app-connection-parameter' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'app-connection-parameter' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/left-panel/dialog-content/dialog-content.component.html:30:6:
7.905       30 │       <app-connection-parameter *ngIf="!showPopUp"  (navigateToInt...
7.905          ╵       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component DialogContentComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/left-panel/dialog-content/dialog-content.component.ts:12:15:
7.905       12 │   templateUrl: './dialog-content.component.html',
7.905          ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-create-integration' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'app-create-integration' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'app-create-integration' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/left-panel/dialog-content/dialog-content.component.html:34:6:
7.905       34 │       <app-create-integration *ngIf="showPopUp" (navigateToCreateC...
7.905          ╵       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component DialogContentComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/left-panel/dialog-content/dialog-content.component.ts:12:15:
7.905       12 │   templateUrl: './dialog-content.component.html',
7.905          ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-create-connection-parameter' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'app-create-connection-parameter' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'app-create-connection-parameter' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/left-panel/dialog-content/dialog-content.component.html:35:6:
7.905       35 │       <app-create-connection-parameter *ngIf="!showPopUp" (navigat...
7.905          ╵       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component DialogContentComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/left-panel/dialog-content/dialog-content.component.ts:12:15:
7.905       12 │   templateUrl: './dialog-content.component.html',
7.905          ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/integration-instance/integration-instance.component.html:1:17:
7.905       1 │ <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows cl...
7.905         ╵                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component IntegrationInstanceComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/integration-instance/integration-instance.component.ts:15:15:
7.905       15 │   templateUrl: './integration-instance.component.html',
7.905          ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905 
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'matColumnDef' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
7.905 1. If 'matColumnDef' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
7.905 2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/integration-instance/integration-instance.component.html:14:56:
7.905       14 │ ...r *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay" [matColumnDef]="column">
7.905          ╵                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component IntegrationInstanceComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/integration-instance/integration-instance.component.ts:15:15:
7.905       15 │   templateUrl: './integration-instance.component.html',
7.905          ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/integration-instance/integration-instance.component.html:32:134:
7.905       32 │ ...element)" [ngClass]="{'selected-row': isRowSelected(element)}">...
7.905          ╵              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component IntegrationInstanceComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/integration-instance/integration-instance.component.ts:15:15:
7.905       15 │   templateUrl: './integration-instance.component.html',
7.905          ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/right-panel.component.html:7:8:
7.905       7 │         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
7.905         ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component RightPanelComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/right-panel.component.ts:6:15:
7.905       6 │   templateUrl: './right-panel.component.html',
7.905         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.html:18:4:
7.905       18 │     <mat-icon>find_in_page</mat-icon>
7.905          ╵     ~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component UserLoginMappingComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.ts:6:15:
7.905       6 │   templateUrl: './user-login-mapping.component.html',
7.905         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.html:20:4:
7.905       20 │     <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
7.905          ╵     ~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component UserLoginMappingComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.ts:6:15:
7.905       6 │   templateUrl: './user-login-mapping.component.html',
7.905         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.html:24:19:
7.905       24 │   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-...
7.905          ╵                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component UserLoginMappingComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.ts:6:15:
7.905       6 │   templateUrl: './user-login-mapping.component.html',
7.905         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905 
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:
7.905 1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7.905 2. If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.html:28:8:
7.905       28 │         <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
7.905          ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component UserLoginMappingComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.ts:6:15:
7.905       6 │   templateUrl: './user-login-mapping.component.html',
7.905         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905
7.905 ✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'matColumnDef' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
7.905 1. If 'matColumnDef' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
7.905 2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. [plugin angular-compiler]
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.html:33:58:
7.905       33 │ ...r *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay" [matColumnDef]="column">
7.905          ╵                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7.905
7.905   Error occurs in the template of component UserLoginMappingComponent.
7.905
7.905     src/app/layout/right-panel/user-login-mapping/user-login-mapping.component.ts:6:15:
7.905       6 │   templateUrl: './user-login-mapping.component.html',
7.905         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I need to generate the image and run the application. i can able to build the angular application and run it locally via ng build or ng serve. I'm facing error only via docker. Can you help me?
